# QT request https url, ok in windows ko in linux

Tags: qt, https, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I have the following code in QT that correctly get the webpage in Windows ( 7 x64 ) but not in Linux Debian 9.13

```
    void Mycl::getdata()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QString urlStr="https://.......");
    QUrl url(urlStr);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    connect (networkManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(done(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->get(request);
}

void Mycl::done(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QString data = QString(reply->readAll ());
```

in Debian i get the folowing error at runtime:

Warning: QSslSocket: OpenSSL >= 1.1.1 is required; OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019 was found instead ((null):0, (null))

Warning: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed ((null):0, (null))

Debug: "TLS initialization failed" (../Shiva2/mycl.cpp:65, void Mycl::done(QNetworkReply*))

I have the following package installed in the os:

ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                1.0.2u-1~deb9u6                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries

ii  libssl1.1:amd64                  1.1.0l-1~deb9u4                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries

ii  libssl-dev:amd64                 1.1.0l-1~deb9u4                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files

ii  openssl                          1.1.0l-1~deb9u4                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility

I don't know if the error is related to this packages... any suggestion? thanks

UPDATE:
Trying to update packages to debian bullseye ( stable ) I get the following error on a dependency :

```
dpkg -i libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks locales (<< 2.31)
  locales (version 2.24-11+deb9u4) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing libc6:amd64 would break locales, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb
```

also i can't upgrade full os cause it's a  virtual server in rent.
Which version of QT i should use?

Comment: The warning is pretty clear, isn't it? You need to have v1.1.1 of OpenSSL, but you have 1.1.0. Are you able to upgrade your OpenSSL?

Comment: see my update above

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have to have openssl version 1.1.1 or higher. But Debian 9 out-of-the-box supports only 1.1.0. So you have to either upgrade openssl or downgrade Qt. [Here](https://bugcheck.win/2018/10/30/installing-nginx-1-14-openssl-1-1-1-on-debian-9/)  you can find how to upgrade openssl in debian 9.

And of course you can update your OS but it look like the trickiest way, though. :)

Comment: see my update above

Comment: Since a haven't solution for proper upgrading openssl in debian and it offtop for this question, I would recommend you to google solution for installation openssl 1.1.1 in debian 9 or create a new question with approrpriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the openssl version provided by you OS and the one required by QT.

Avoid up/down-grading your OS openssl version, try connecting to the QNetworkAccessManager signal:

```
void QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors)
```

and, in your slot, invoke `reply->ignoreSslErrors()`.

If that does not work, copy the QT openssl .so files somewhere in your PATH.